# Erro em aplicação Java simples: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um curso de Java e fui resolver um exercício simples onde eu deveria ler dois números inteiros do teclado e mostrar a soma deles. Porém no console recebo o erro *Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m* após o programa mostrar a soma dos números. Acredito que não seja um erro do código, pode ser algum erro de configuração do Java?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a, b;

        System.out.printf("Digite um valor inteiro: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("%nDigite outro valor inteiro: ");
        b = sc.nextInt();

        a = a + b;

        System.out.printf("%nA soma dos valores digitados: %d", a);

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

No console aparece o seguinte:

[image: Console]

Comment: Percebi que isso aparece no final de todo programa que faço, não interfere no funcionamento mas queria saber o motivo.

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente tem uma variável de ambiente configurada com esse nome "_JAVA_OPTIONS" e o conteúdo dela é "-Xmx4069m", por padrão o java ao reconhecer que o SO tem uma variável de ambiente com esse nome passa a utiliza-la, esse "erro" na verdade é apenas uma indicação do seu java de que ele está "pegando" essa configuração.

Para remover isso basta deletar a variável "_JAVA_OPTIONS" das suas variaveis de ambiente do windows. Como sua configuração é bem simples, não vai afetar o funcionamento do seu java remover a variável.